# main out of sync with origin/main

Tags: git, github

Not sure what I did wrong, but my main branch somehow ended up out of sync with origin:

```
> git graph
* xxxfee2 (origin/branch2, branch2) Redacted
* xxx26ed Redacted
| *   xxxa7ad (origin/main) Merge pull request #1 from user/branch2
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | xxx936b Redacted
* | xxx7202 Redacted
...
* | xxxd12d Redacted
* | xxx0dce Redacted
* | xxx866c Merge branch 'branch2' of https://github.com/user/repo into branch2
|\|
* | ccc0cae (refs/original/refs/heads/branch2) Update .gitignore for new conf files
* | ccc6c4d Redacted
* | ccca660 Redacted
* | ccce7a6 Redacted
|/
* xxxbfee (HEAD -> main) Redacted
* xxxd2ce Redacted
```

I think it might've happened when I accidentally pushed sensitive information and used filter-repo to undo.
Or because I used Github (the website) instead of cli to merge into main.

On Github it looks like this:

[image]

Now I can't merge branch2.

Comment: If your branch is called main, please don't also call it master. Using two names for the same thing is just confusing. If your local copy of main is behind the copy on GitHub, did you try checking out the main branch, doing a pull, then checking out your branch2, merging main into it? Then it would no longer be behind main.

Comment: Apologies. My default branch is called main. I've edited the title to reflect that. I checked out local main, did a fetch (without errors), but trying to merge leads to `fatal: No remote for the current branch`. Weirdly, `remote -v` lists remotes for both pushing and fetching.

Comment: Did you merge main into branch2 locally? `git checkout branch2` then `git merge main`?

Comment: Disregard the fatal error. I was running `git merge` while I should've run `git merge origin/main`. So your solution works. Now everything is back in sync. Many thanks.